# how can i keep listening for bluetooth scanner input in my app when device goes sleep or locked

Tags: android, bluetooth

One of the activity in my app connects to bluetooth scanner and get the input and display it in a listview. I got that working by following the bluetooth chat sample app. now the issue is, whenever screen is locked, or device goes to powersave mode, my connection with bluetooth scanner is getting disconnected. how can continue to keep the connection stays on until app is really closed from the system? I am new to Android . I did some search it says to use wakeful lock but how can i do that?  Some samples would be much appreciated!  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using wakeful lock, I would recommend you to implement the connection inside a background service.
The service runs until its killed by the system or you stop it.

You can found information including a simple example here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html